# How to split a file into n parts in java?

Tags: java, file, io

I have done one application in java which do same operations over the file. Actually what my application do is just perform a threshold scheme (n,k) for a file. This is working perfectly but i am able to understand it because of i use System.out.println () method . What i actually i want to do is just to really split the file . For example if i have file myfile.txt and i use threshold scheme(7,3) i really want to split my file into 7 parts like myfile.txt1 , myfile.txt2 and so on . What i really have done till now is :

```
 public  int[][] calculateThresholdScheme(byte[] secret, int n, int k, RndGeneratorAllAlgorithm rnd,FastFiniteField256 galoa) {

                /* secret is the content of the file in byte
                 * n is in how many parts we will share the file
                 * k means that from n parts of shares we need k parts to take file back
                 * rnd is an algorithm which generate random numbers
                 * galoa is a finite field 256 which perform mathematical operation
              */


   if (secret == null)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("null secret"); 
   // throws exceptions if parameters of our method do not meet the conditions of SSS

   int m = secret.length;

   if (m == 0) // the secret length must  not be 0
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid secret length: 0");


   if (n < 1) // we should have at least one share
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enought shares: " + n);


   if (n > MaxShares) // we can not have integer shares greater than 256 
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("too many shares: " + n + "(gt" + MaxShares + ")");


   if (k > n) // threshold can not be bigger than shares
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("threshold > shares: " + k + " > " + n);

       /**We must take a two dimensional vector of share which will contain all pairs of share for each byte of file
         for example (1,f(1)) , (2,f(2)) , (3,f(3)) where 1,2,3 are the value of shares */


   int[][] share = new int[n][m + 1]; // this one will only create a two dimensional array

   /*
   System.out.println("It has " + n + " rows , and " +m + " columns");
   System.out.println("The number of rows means in how much shares we will share each byte");
    System.out.println("The number of columns means how bytes our file has");
   */

       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
       share[j][0] =  (j + 1);


      for (int j=0;j<m;j++) { //this will take bytes of files one by one (fix column)

       // each byte of the file will be the secret
          coeff=secret[j]; 


       // create an array of size k where k is the number of random coefficients 
            allCoefficients=new int[k];


            // call generateCoefficents method and assign its content to the array allCoefficients
          allCoefficients=rnd.supply(k,coeff);

    //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allCoefficients));

           for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {

   share [i][j+1]= (byte)galoa.hornerEvaluation(share[i][0],allCoefficients);


          } // close nested loop which goes through rows


       } // close outer loop which goes through columns

     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString("share");
     return share;
   }
```

This really works good . For example if i have one file let say just for demonstration 11 byte . for first byte we will have 7 value for second byte 7 values and so on. Now i am really struggled of how to really use this method which split the file in order to really split my file which i have into my desktop into seven parts. In other words i want this method i have here to do something similar with split() method which is in java api.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't know what k means.

Comment: * k means that from n parts of shares we need k parts to take file back